# Using APIs in a React Template

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, api, frontend

I am learning the ropes of React and JavaScript.  I started by grabbing a free template I found from [GitHub](https://github.com/cruip/open-react-template).  After creating a few other pages, I connected the app to a Django back end and created a model with two entries.

[image]

The objective is to be able to display the information from the model like title, objective, etc.  I'm also new to using APIs to get this information, so I've been looking through various places online, but I just can't figure out how to fit in the code examples online with the code I have from the template from GitHub.

One of the places I've looked:  https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Below is `Hero.js`.  This is routed to the home page and it's just what the template provider named it.  The code example provided above and in many other places I've looked puts all their code in `App.js`.  I know they're just doing that for demonstration purposes, but I'm not sure how to fit it into the template code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { SectionProps } from '../../utils/SectionProps';
import ButtonGroup from '../elements/ButtonGroup';
import Button from '../elements/Button';
import Image from '../elements/Image';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const propTypes = {
  ...SectionProps.types
}

const defaultProps = {
  ...SectionProps.defaults
}

const Hero = ({
  className,
  topOuterDivider,
  bottomOuterDivider,
  topDivider,
  bottomDivider,
  hasBgColor,
  invertColor,
  ...props
}) => {

  const outerClasses = classNames(
    'hero section center-content',
    topOuterDivider && 'has-top-divider',
    bottomOuterDivider && 'has-bottom-divider',
    hasBgColor && 'has-bg-color',
    invertColor && 'invert-color',
    className
  );

  const innerClasses = classNames(
    'hero-inner section-inner',
    topDivider && 'has-top-divider',
    bottomDivider && 'has-bottom-divider'
  );

  return (
    <section
      {...props}
      className={outerClasses}
    >
      <div className="container-sm">
        <div className={innerClasses}>
          <div className="hero-content">
            <h1 className="mt-0 mb-16 reveal-from-bottom" data-reveal-delay="200">
              BlueBird <span className="text-color-primary">Teaching</span>
            </h1>
            <div className="container-xs">
              <p className="m-0 mb-32 reveal-from-bottom" data-reveal-delay="400">
                An open source approach to education. 
                </p>
              <div className="reveal-from-bottom" data-reveal-delay="600">
                <ButtonGroup>
                  <Button tag="a" color="primary" wideMobile>
                    <Link to="/About">How This Works</Link>
                    </Button>
                  <Button tag="a" color="dark" wideMobile>
                    <Link to="/Test">Other Open Source Resources</Link>
                    </Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="hero-figure reveal-from-bottom illustration-element-01" data-reveal-value="20px" data-reveal-delay="800">
            <h2>Current Focus:</h2>
            <h3 style={{ color: '#5b92e5' }}>(title)</h3>
            <p style={{ textAlign: 'left', color: 'white' }}><strong>Objective: </strong>(Objective goes here)</p>
            <p style={{ textAlign: 'left', color: 'white' }}>(Description goes here)</p>
            <p style={{ textAlign: 'left', color: 'white', fontSize: 15 }}>The expected completion date of this focus is: (expected_completion_date)</p>
            <h3>Preview</h3>
              <Image style={{ padding: '30px' }}
                src={require('./../../assets/images/Screenshot from 2020-08-03 07-52-33.png')}
                alt="Hero"
                width={896}
                height={504} />
              <Image
                src={require('./../../assets/images/Screenshot from 2020-08-03 07-53-08.png')}
                alt="Hero"
                width={896}
                height={504} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

Hero.propTypes = propTypes;
Hero.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Hero;
```

If needed, below is `App.js`.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoute from './utils/AppRoute';
import ScrollReveal from './utils/ScrollReveal';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

// Layouts
import LayoutDefault from './layouts/LayoutDefault';

// Views 
import Home from './views/Home';
import Test from './views/test';
import About from './views/About';
import Contact from './views/Contact';

// Initialize Google Analytics
ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_GA_CODE);



const trackPage = page => {
  ReactGA.set({ page });
  ReactGA.pageview(page);
};

const App = () => {

  const childRef = useRef();
  let location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const page = location.pathname;
    document.body.classList.add('is-loaded')
    childRef.current.init();
    trackPage(page);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <ScrollReveal
      ref={childRef}
      children={() => (
        <Switch>
          <AppRoute exact path="/" component={Home} layout={LayoutDefault} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/test" component={Test} layout={LayoutDefault} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/about" component={About} layout={LayoutDefault} />
          <AppRoute exact path="/contact" component={Contact} layout={LayoutDefault} />
        </Switch>
      )} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for any help and explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to get your data from API and use it in your application.

Here is an little example for you with comments

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Example() {
  // Define our datas variable in state as an empty Array
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

  // useEffect will called after component will be rendered
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch our data from our API
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")
      // Resolve the responsove data
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        // Show data in console
        console.log(json)
        // Set our API data to our datas array
        setDatas([...json]);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {/* 
            map is a build-in javascript function too loop through objects like foreach 
            So we just loop our array and render in our application
        */}

        {datas.map((data, i) => (
          <li key={i}> {data.title} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I use javascript **Fetch API** function to get data from API but if you want, you can use something like **Axios** too.

If we want to use axios we just need to change useEffect like this for example;

First we need to install axios

```
npm install axios
```

Then, import or require axios

```
import axios from "axios";
// or
const axios = require('axios');
```

After these steps, just change useEffect function like this;

```
axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success and show data in console
    console.log(response.data);
    // Set our API data to our datas array
    setDatas([...response.data]);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Javascript MAP: [Array.prototype.map() - Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Fetch API: [Fetch API - Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Axios: [Axios Github Page](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Axios vs Fetch API: [Fetch vs. Axios.js for making http requests](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5)

Also I would suggest you to build your app from scratch rather than using a template to understand better and remember I just gave you a simple example, if you wanna build something for production you may want to build a different structure for your API requests.

I hope I could help, have a great day :)

Comment: Wonderful!!  This might be obvious, but for anyone looking at this in the future, if you go with the axios solution like I did, you still gotta define the datas variable like shown in the first solution.

Comment: Glad to help :)